# Force java path mac

Tags: java, macos, terminal, java-7, java-home

Before you answer "export JAVA_HOME=whatever >> ~/.bash_profile", just know it won't work. I even restarted my terminal and typed `echo $JAVA_HOME`, and got the right path.

How do you force (and I mean FORCE, not tell-java-it-exists) a custom path for the java home directory. My java 7 in installed in `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java`. Java doesn't recognize the java path. When I type `java -version`, it says `1.7.10_60`. But, when I type `java -version:1.7.10`, it says it doesn't exist. When I launch my binary, it says Java 7 is required. It is a UNIX executable, and won't launch with the `java` command (with or without `-jar`).

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the actual JRE (that path looks like just a plugin installation for applets). You can get it [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)